# product of list of list of letter [[a,b],[c,d],[a,n]]

Tags: python, list, product

I have list of posiple letter for each letter in a word..and I want to find all possiple words.

for example the input is `[[l,b],[e,d],[s,t]]` this represent a word of 3 letter wher first letter could be l or b, second letter could be e or d and third letter is s or t. I wont the out put to be the product of these lists [les,let,bet,...and so on]. the list could be any length not only three.
I tried

```
res = list(map(prod, zip(test_list)))
```

but I get

> [<itertools.product object at 0x0000024F65AEC600>, <itertools.product object at 0x0000024F65AEC640>, <itertools.product object at 0x0000024F65AEC680>, <itertools.product object at 0x0000024F65AEC6C0>]

I tried

```
word1=list(product(letter[0],letter[1],letter[2]))
```

it works perfectly but I want the code to accept any length pf list

Comment: `list(product(*letter))`

Comment: @Mark: Tweaking to `list(map(''.join, product(*letter)))` if you want them to be strings rather than `tuple`s of characters (making the conversion would save quite a bit of memory and might even run faster, given the optimizations in `product` that only apply when the `tuple` it produces is released before the next `tuple` is requested, which `map(''.join, ...)` will do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to `zip` the `test_list`, just pass each element of it as an argument to `product` using the `*` operator:

```
>>> test_list = [['l','b'],['e','d'],['s','t']]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(*test_list))
[('l', 'e', 's'), ('l', 'e', 't'), ('l', 'd', 's'), ('l', 'd', 't'), ('b', 'e', 's'), ('b', 'e', 't'), ('b', 'd', 's'), ('b', 'd', 't')]
```

If you want the result to be in string form, use `join`:

```
>>> [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(*test_list)]
['les', 'let', 'lds', 'ldt', 'bes', 'bet', 'bds', 'bdt']
```